# Is there an algorithm for near optimal partition of the Travelling salesman problem, creating routes that need the same time to complete?

Tags: optimization, time, cluster-computing, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

I have a problem to solve. I need to visit 7962 places with a vehicle. The vehicle travels with 10km/h and each time I visit one place I stay there for 1 minute. I want to divide those 7962 places into subsets that take will take up to 8 hours. So lets say 200 places take 8 hours I visit them and come back the next day to visit another maybe 250 places(the 200 places subsets will require more distance travelled). For the distance I only care for Euclidean Distances no need to take into account the distance through the road network.
[A map of the 7962 places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu7pF.jpg)

What I have done so far is use the k means clustering algorithm to get good enough subsets and then the Lin Kernighan heuristic (Program Concorde) to find the distance. And then compute times. But my results go from 4 hours to 12 hours. Any idea to make it better? Or a code that does this whole task all together. Propose anything but I am not a programmer I just use Python some times.
Set of coordinates :
http://www.filedropper.com/wholesetofcoordinates

Coordinates subsets(40 clusters produces with the k means algorithm):
http://www.filedropper.com/kmeans40clusters

Comment: Can you share (sub) set of the data? This is indeed a classical TSP.  I don't see how the 1minute or 8 hour effect the problem. Isn't that just 'cut' the end result into chunks of 8 hours?

Comment: I edited the post to share the data. Yes I do not care about the amount of time what I want to know if there are algorithms designed for this kind of problem from my brief online research it seems that its like the MTSP(multi-TSP) problem or the CTSP(clustered-TSP) but the problem is that I do not care just for the distance travelled but also for the nodes visited. Can you suggest me literature-methods to look at?

Comment: I cannot cut the end result into chunks of 8 hours because in the end result the salesman starts from one of 7962 cities and ends there. What I want is to create from the 7962 cities TSP, 40 or so TSP problems that given the time information its one of them will take as close to a certain amount of time to complete(8 hours in my case). Like If we had 40 or so salesman and 8 hours of their time and wanted to send them to visit all of the 7962 destinations.

Comment: I see. Are there restictions on there the 40 salespersons can start, and/or stop? Do they all have to start in same point? Do they have to end there they start?